# Determine whether any popup is currently open in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Using Leaflet.js, I'm trying to implement a UI pattern whereby if a popup is open, and the user clicks on another part of the map, this should be taken to be an implied popup close.

To do this, I therefore need to determine whether a popup is actually open. I cannot seem to get a proper handle to it. I can't find any examples on the internet of how to do this.

In my code, I have multiple layers (any of which could contain a popup), each of which is created using:

```
dataLayers[index] = L.geoJson (url, {
    pointToLayer: ...,
    onEachFeature ...,
    // etc.
)};
```

I would expect to do something like:

```
var popup;
$.each (dataLayers, function (index, dataLayer) {
    dataLayer.eachLayer (function (layer) {
        popup = layer.getPopup ();
        if (popup.isOpen ()) {
            console.log ('An opened popup is present; do stuff...');
        }
    });
});
```

If I do `console.log` on `layer` (as created by `dataLayer.eachLayer`), I get an object of type `i`, which has member properties like `feature`, `dragging`, `options`, etc.

If I do `console.log` on `popup` (as created by `layer.getPopup ()`), I get an object of type `i`, which has member properties like `options`, `_content`, etc.

The `_content` value is a string contains the prospective text of each popup. So it feels like I'm targeting the right thing.

But the `console.log` call in the middle doesn't ever execute when a popup is visible, and there are no console errors.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

It's possible other handlers interfering perhaps, which is hard to check. But does the above code look correct?

Comment: Consider listening to the [`popupopen` and `popupclose` events](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#layer-popupopen) (fired by all subclasses of `L.Layer`); this way you can be aware of changes in the system state.

Comment: @IvanSanchez: Thanks; this was useful in debugging the problem. I've put the reason in my self-answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found why this was happening - the popup will implicitly close due to `closeOnClick` being on, and that handler means the popup closes just before the above loop is run, and thus it will never return true.

The solution was to set `closeOnClick` to be `false`, then in a map click handler, use the above code but firstly close the popup using `map.closePopup ()`.